# Convert an integer variable to a `first_digit.second_digit` format

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I want convert an integer variable into a specific string format.
This integer (for example: `56`, `71`, `80`) needs to be converted into a string formatted `first_digit.second_digit` (for example `5.6`, `7.1`).

How can I do this?

I tried a mixture of Python and Jinja but it doesn't work.

With:

```yaml
- name: Install PHP > 5.6
  apt: 
    name: 
      - "php{{ str(php) | php[0]+'.'+php[1] }}"    
  when: php > 56
```

I get this error:

> template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '['. String: php{{ str(php) | php[0]+'.'+php[1] }}

Comment: This could soon be error prone, what will happen when PHP reason version `10.0` and your code is going to assume you want version `1.0`?

Comment: I know, but this is a temporary solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the variable

```yaml
  php: 56
```

Convert the integer to a [string](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.string) and split the first digit from the rest (this will work while the PHP major version is a single digit)

```yaml
  php_str: "{{ php|string }}"
  php_ver: "{{ php_str[0] }}.{{ php_str[1:] }}"
```

To test the [version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) you can declare a variable. For example,

```yaml
  php_ver_min: '5.5'
```

and try the debug

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Install php{{ php_ver }}"
      when: php_ver is version(php_ver_min, '>=')
      vars:
        php_str: "{{ php|string }}"
        php_ver: "{{ php_str[0] }}.{{ php_str[1:] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Install php5.6
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    php: 56
    php_ver_min: '5.5'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Install php{{ php_ver }}"
      when: php_ver is version(php_ver_min, '>=')
      vars:
        php_str: "{{ php|string }}"
        php_ver: "{{ php_str[0] }}.{{ php_str[1:] }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, its work. I thought for a long time how to select another variable)